# Allow anonymous access to a specific page in a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

The sharepoint site doesn't allow anonymous access and uses forms authentication, however I have custom page in "_layouts/" that anonymous users need to be able to access.

I thought it would be enough to add a `<location></location>` tag in the web.config with the correct path that allowed anonymous access (`<allow users="*" />`), however, this seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was a bit deeper. The page in question was set to use a masterpage dynamically which anonymous users did not have access. Otherwise the `<location></location>` tag did work.